# Next.js custom error component doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, next.js, custom-error-pages

I'm having problem with Next.js custom error component.

I followed documentation and made 404.js component in my /pages but it looks like it isn't recognized, it still shows me default error page. Thanks for anyone who opened this question anyway!

```
export default function Custom404() { return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1> }
```

Comment: Please [show the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}

pages/404.js

Comment: which nextjs version are you using?

Comment: version is 13.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Custom error page is available for [Next.js 9.3](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#automatic-static-optimization-for-404) and afterward, so maybe you are using an older version which has not supported yet

Comment: version is 13.5.4

Comment: are you using app router or page router?

Comment: im using page router

Comment: @FreedomFighter Maybe you have `cache` problem (delete your .next folder and try to build again)

Comment: Did that already :/

Comment: Can you show the `next.config.js` file?

Comment: /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig